# Select and use a driver with mismatching PID on x64 systems

Tags: 64-bit, driver, signature, pid

The Silicon Labs CP210x chip allows the PID to be customized which in turn means a customized driver is needed to have a matching PID. On x64 systems that require driver signing using a customized driver would also require signing that driver. Fortunately it is possible to use the original signed CP210x driver by manually select it for the device as explained [here](http://forum.pololu.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2271).

What I would like to know is if it is possible to use DPinst or some other method to automatically have the original signed CP210x driver selected for the device during install or when the CP210x device is plugged in?

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can write a service that will be monitoring for device changes and install a driver for CP210x.